# iOS - Handling Remote Push Notifications From Background Vs. Foreground

Tags: ios, objective-c, push-notification

I need to handle remote push notifications based on when I get them. When the app is in the background or terminated and if I get a push notification, and when I tap the push notification, I handle that in `

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo
```

where I can tell the visible `UIViewController` to push to the necessary view.

However, when I receive a remote push notification while I'm already inside the app, I don't want the app to do anything but increment the notifications counter on the home view. Right now it does the same thing, which pushes to the necessary view, but this should only be happening when the app was at first in the background and the user tapped the push notification to enter the app.

How do I differentiate between these two use cases?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can check the "applicationState" property of UIApplication class.

```
UIApplicationState applicationState = [UIApplication sharedApplication].applicationState;

if(applicationState==UIApplicationStateActive){
NSLog(@"push message received when app was active"):
}else{
}
```

You can do this check in the below delegate method which you already use.

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo
```

Hope it helps!!

Comment: This worked perfectly! Thank you very much! The flow and order of how everything was handled really confused me :D

Comment: I am glad to help you!!

Comment: Can you post this in swift?I still got error at ApplicationState if condition

Comment: hi , i have a similar scenario but slightly modification required ,but like when i get the push notification ,the app would get active in background and do the task given in  ,- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo  , but my app would not get active until user taps on the notification . so , how would i get this done while app is in background ? dose anyone know the solution for this ?